# ClassNotFoundException on opening facebook share icon in android

Tags: android, facebook

I have an android application, and I added a share on facebook option, as described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/

On my smartphone the share dialog works perfectly, yet on all my friends phones the dialog opens and closes instantly. I asked one of them to send me logcat output and this is what he saw:

```
E/Parcel(2939): Class not found when unmarshalling: com.facebook.ipc.composer.intent.SharePreview, 
e: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.ipc.composer.intent.SharePreview
```

I do not know what that class is, and found nothing on google about it.
The facebook package I downloaded did not contain it.
I am not sure this is what is causing the share dialog to close instantly, but it is a prime suspect.

I will be glad if you can help!

Comment: Alexander, did you find a solution to this? I could not find any "sandbox" info in the developer pages. If you had a link, I'd love to see it, thanks.

Comment: Actually the link Johnz posted worked for me. Perhaps facebook changed it later. Perhaps try to go to Status & Review > 'Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?', change it to 'Yes'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems your facebook app is on sandbox mode.

For it to work, you have to set up your facebook app at developers.facebook.com to production mode, then and only then other people will be able to use it. Else the only one who could use it is the facebook user who created the app.

For more info about sandbox mode go here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/register-facebook-application/

Cheers!

Comment: That link is dead and a search for "facebook sandbox" produces nothing targeted. If you knew of an updated link that'd be great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is to make the app in general public mode

[image]